# windows 7: how to run a bat when specific program start?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

For the moment I'm using a bat which launch the program. But I would like the bat to run automatically when the program launch.

I did look into the task scheduler but this option seems to be missing.

Comment: As it currently stands, your question isn't very clear. You could write a batch script that, among other things, launch a particular program, but I guess that's not quite what you have in mind. Please clarify what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I don't want to launch my app through the bat. I want the .bat to be launch when my app start. Eg: when Chrome browser start it will launch the bat.

Answer (score 1):

This may work based on your comment of wanting to start a batch file when Chrome is found to be running on your PC.

```
ECHO OFF
TASKLIST | FIND /I "Chrome.exe"
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 EXIT
CALL "C:\Batch\Batchfile.bat"
EXIT
```

The part that I'm not sure about here is once the batch starts, how you tell the tasklist process to not run any longer to keep launching it.